# Laravel/Ajax - Load more results without new results conflicting with the request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

On my website, there are articles, and articles have comments.

When someone pulls up an article, the default comment sort is by "New".

My first controller will pull up the article along with 10 comments (I only use 10 for testing purposes, in reality it'll be like 200).

```
$submission = Submission::where('id', $id)->first();
$comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)
            ->where('parent_id', NULL)
            ->orderBy('removed','asc')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

I also have a second controller that is used to load more comments on an article through AJAX.

```
public function loadMoreNewComments($submissionID, $skip, Request $request) {

    $submission  = Submission::findOrFail($submissionID);

    if($request->ajax()) {

        $comments = $submission->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip($skip)->take(10)->get();

        return [
            'replies' => view('partials.comment_loop')->with('submission', $submission)->with('comments', $comments)->render(),
        ];  

    }

}
```

This will make it so that when you click the "view more comments" button, you get 10 more results.

This uses a `$skip` count, which skips a certain amount of results based on how many has been loaded. So since we're loading 10 at a time in this example, the first `$skip` count will  be 10, then the second time will be 20, then 30, etc. and then it will `take(10)` results after the ones that have been skipped.

This is what it looks like in my blade view:

```
<div id="comment-thread-container">
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    @include('partials.comment_block')  
@endforeach
</div>


@if ($comments->total() > 10)
        <span id="viewMoreNewComments" data-submission-id="{{ $submission->id }}" data-skip="10">
            <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            View More Comments (<span id="viewComments-count">{{$comments->total() - 10}}</span>)
        </span>
@endif
```

And this is what the javascript request looks like:

```
$(document).on('click','#viewMoreNewComments', function(){
    $submissionID = $(this).attr('data-submission-id');

    $skipCount = parseInt($(this).attr('data-skip'));

    $remainingCommentCount = parseInt($('#viewComments-count').text());

    var page = host + "/load-more-comments/" + $submissionID + "/" + $skipCount;

    var skip = $skipCount + 10; 

    if(page !== null) {
        $.get(page, function(data){
            $('#comment-thread-container').append(data.replies);
            $('#viewMoreNewComments').attr('data-skip', skip);
            $('#viewComments-count').html($remainingCommentCount - 10);
        });
        if ($remainingCommentCount - 10 < 1) {
            $('#viewMoreNewComments').remove();
        }
    }

});
```

Now this will work just fine, until you have users posting comments AFTER you've loaded the page.

Because when a user posts a comment after you've loaded the page, it sets the count back by one.

So, for example, if you load an article, and while you read the article 3 more comments are made, if you click on the "View More Comments" button, you'll see 3 duplicate comments that were already loaded.

I have no idea how to fix this. It will be an even bigger problem once I implement sorting by "best score", as comments can have upvotes and downvotes, as the top rated comments might change drastically from the time a user starts reading an article to when they finish.

What would be a solution to this? Keeping an array of all the comment IDs that have already been loaded in cache and then passing that array with each request? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: The way I would do this is by keeping the time when the user load the first 10 comments, then, when he click show more, you can set a rule to ignore comment created after the time he first loaded. And so, you can create a rule for comment created after the time.

Comment: Smart. But what about when I sort by score?

Comment: Well, I consider every kind of sort or filter as a refresh. The user will return to the top of the new collections. Then change the time and restart your counter.

Comment: @ElieMorin  i'm not sure I follow. Maybe post an answer? Pseudocode will do if you like.

Comment: If your comments have auto-generated IDs, I would use those in case you sort by creation date. If you have newest first, the auto IDs will be highest to lowest. If you take 10 comments, say IDs 90 to 80, you can then in your ajax request send the last ID (e.g. 80), and in your controller filter by comments `ID < 80`. This has the advantage that auto-IDs are indexed and your query will be way faster than using offset/limit (skip/take). See for example here https://developer.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/an-efficient-alternative-to-paging-with-sql-offsets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for Matthias S who suggested to use auto increments id instead of created_at.

I suggest you to keep track of 3 things on server side since you can sort more then one columns.

The column (ex: id/score), the last value and the sort order (asc/desc).
Your new call will look like something like this

```
var page = host + "/load-more-comments/" + $submissionID + "/" + $column + "/" + $lastValue + "/" + $sort;
```

And so your new call will look like:

```
public function loadMoreNewComments($submissionID, $skip, Request $request) {

    $submission  = Submission::findOrFail($submissionID);

    if($request->ajax()) {

        $comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)
                           ->orderBy($column, $sort)
                           ->when(true, function($query) use ($column, $lastValue, $sort) {
                               if ($sort === 'desc') {
                                  return $query->where($column, '<', $lastValue);
                               } else {
                                  return $query->where($column, '>', $lastValue);
                               }
                           })
                           ->take(10);

        return [
            'replies' => view('partials.comment_loop')->with('submission', $submission)->with('comments', $comments)->render(),
        ];  

    }

}
```

EDIT:
Since more then one comment can have the same score, you will also have to keep an array of all the id where the score is equal to the last value when you sort by score. Send this array to the server and use a code similar to this one instead:

```
        $comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)
                           ->orderBy($column, $sort)
                           ->when($column === 'id', function($query) use ($lastValue, $sort) {
                               if ($sort === 'desc') {
                                  return $query->where('id', '<', $lastValue);
                               } else {
                                  return $query->where('id', '>', $lastValue);
                               }
                           })->when($column !== 'id', function($query) use ($column, $lastValue, $sort, $arrayOfIds) {
                               if ($sort === 'desc') {
                                  return $query->where($column, '<=', $lastValue)->whereNotIn('id', $arrayOfIds);
                               } else {
                                  return $query->where($column, '>=', $lastValue)->whereNotIn('id', $arrayOfIds);
                               }
                           })->take(10);
```